# Add parent name to term list in dropdown (eg. coupon category list)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We have a WooCommerce clothing store and want to create coupons that have certain categories excluded. Our category structure is as follows (simplified):

```
– Men
– – Shirts
– – Jeans
– – Sale
– Women
– – Shirts
– – Jeans
– – Sale
```

However when we want to select [Men » Sale] from the *Exclude categories* dropdown picker in [WooCommerce » Marketing » Coupons » Usage Restriction] the list is flattened:

```
– Jeans
– Men
– Sale
– Sale
– Shirts
– Shirts
– Women
```

Now it is not clear which categories are actually the one we want to exclude. Have in min, this is a very simplified structure, in the live environment this is even worse.

I hoped for an `apply_filter` but the `get_terms()` apparently does have none in code, see [source code on github here »](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/902454a40c352915b4faea11253e722cec359c3f/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-coupon-data.php#L233) (line #233)

`$categories = get_terms('product_cat', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0');`

Since this is not filtered, I don’t see a way to add a parent category to have this as the desired outcome:

```
- Men
- Men » Jeans
- Men » Shirts
- Men » Sale
- Women
- Women » Jeans
- Women » Shirts
- Women » Sale
```

Any idea how to get that list now that there is no filter in the code?

For example, this is what we use for a third party plugin that also uses the WooCommerce category terms, but that actually *does* have a filter on the get_terms and the native WooCommerce code on coupons does not...

Example:

```php
if (!function_exists('yith_wcbep_add_parent_category_name')) {
    function yith_wcbep_add_parent_category_name($terms, $args) {
        $term_name = '';
        $taxonomy  = isset($args['taxonomy']) ? $args['taxonomy'] : '';
        foreach ($terms as $term_id => $term_name) {
            $term = get_term_by('id', $term_id, $taxonomy);
            $term_name = isset($term->name) ? $term->name : '';
            if (isset($term->parent) && $term->parent > 0) {
                $parent = get_term_by('id', $term->parent, $term->taxonomy);
                $term_name = $parent->name . ' > ' . $term_name;
                $terms[$term_id] = $term_name;
            }
        }
        return $terms;
    }
    add_filter('yith_plugin_fw_json_search_found_terms', 'yith_wcbep_add_parent_category_name', 10, 2);
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to exclude on sale products from coupons just add the restriction on the coupon itself? Its big mistake to have 10 categories named sale. You can filter products on sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting feature to solve, seems kind of strange Woocommerce doesn't have hierarchy names in the coupons categories.
So I did some digging and found that the only appropriate filter seems to be `get_terms`, after some trial and error I came up with this.

```php
if (!function_exists('btAddHierarchyNameToCouponsCat')) {
    function btAddHierarchyNameToCouponsCat($terms)
    {
        if (!is_admin()) {
            return $terms;
        }
    
        global $pagenow;
    
        if ($pagenow !== 'post-new.php' && $pagenow !== 'post.php') {
            return $terms;
        }
    
        if (
            (
                !empty($_GET['post_type'])
                && $_GET['post_type'] === 'shop_coupon'
            )
            || (
                !empty($_GET['post'])
                && get_post_type($_GET['post']) === 'shop_coupon'
                && !empty($_GET['action'])
                && $_GET['action'] === 'edit'
            )
        ) {
            foreach ($terms as &$term) {
                $term->name = (function ($term) {
                    $fullName = array_map(function ($ancestorId) {
                        $ancestor = get_term_by('term_id', $ancestorId, 'product_cat');
    
                        return $ancestor->name;
                    }, array_reverse(get_ancestors($term->term_id, 'product_cat')));
    
                    $fullName[] = $term->name;
    
                    return implode(' -> ', $fullName);
                })($term);
            }
    
            return $terms;
        }
    
        return $terms;
    }

    add_filter('get_terms', 'btAddHierarchyNameToCouponsCat');
}
```

Here is the before.

[image]

And here is the after.

[image]

The general idea of this filter is to specifically work only when creating or editing a coupon on the dashboard.
Then it updates the category name to contain the whole hierarchy of the categories names.
This might not be perfect but it's a starting point

Comment: That's what I though, odd that they don't have a filter in place by default, right? But I like this method, it's clean and simple(ish) and worked like a charm. Thanks @Buttered_Toast!

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue, what you can do is to clone WooCommerce coupon product categories restrictions section, customizing the categories output as you like *(here *I add the parent term name to the category name)*, removing with JavaScript the related HTML output from the default WooCommerce ones.

So you will get the following:

[image]

Here is the hooked function code:

```
// Prepend the parent term name to the term name output
function prepend_parent_term_name( $term, $sep = ' > ' ) {
    if (isset($term->parent) && $term->parent > 0) {
        $parent_name = get_term_by('id', $term->parent, $term->taxonomy)->name;
        return esc_html( $parent_name ) . $sep . esc_html( $term->name );
    } else {
        return esc_html( $term->name );
    }
}

// Replace WooCommerce Admin Coupon product categories restictions section with a custom one
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_usage_restriction', 'action_coupon_options_usage_restriction', 10, 2 );
function action_coupon_options_usage_restriction( $coupon_id, $coupon ) {
    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    // Categories.
    ?>
    <p class="form-field">
        <label for="product_categories2"><?php _e( 'Product categories', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <select id="product_categories2" name="product_categories[]" style="width: 50%;"  class="wc-enhanced-select" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Any category', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
            <?php
            $category_ids = $coupon->get_product_categories( 'edit' );
            $categories   = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );

            if ( $categories ) {
                foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '"' . wc_selected( $cat->term_id, $category_ids ) . '>' . prepend_parent_term_name( $cat ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select> <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'Product categories that the coupon will be applied to, or that need to be in the cart in order for the "Fixed cart discount" to be applied.', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
    </p>

    <?php // Exclude Categories. ?>
    <p class="form-field">
        <label for="exclude_product_categories2"><?php _e( 'Exclude categories', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <select id="exclude_product_categories2" name="exclude_product_categories[]" style="width: 50%;"  class="wc-enhanced-select" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'No categories', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
            <?php
            $category_ids = $coupon->get_excluded_product_categories( 'edit' );
            $categories   = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );

            if ( $categories ) {
                foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
                    echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '"' . wc_selected( $cat->term_id, $category_ids ) . '>' . prepend_parent_term_name( $cat ) . '</option>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php echo wc_help_tip( __( 'Product categories that the coupon will not be applied to, or that cannot be in the cart in order for the "Fixed cart discount" to be applied.', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?>
    </p>
    <?php // Removing default product categories restrictions html  ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#product_categories').parent().parent().remove();
    });
    </script>
    <?php 
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I eventually ended up using @Buttered_Toast his method which is a bit cleaner since it only changes the actual terms list without touching html/javascript. But even though I didn't use your code, I see what you're doing here and like the creative workaround of it. +1